# Why isn't my else statement working? It prints "This book isn't available in Library" several times instead of once

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

```
file=open('database.txt','r')
x=input("Please enter the title of the book you are looking for?")
print("%s %10s %8s %22s %11s"%\
  ("ID","Title","Author","Purchase Date","Member ID"))
for line in file:
if x in line.split():
    print(line)
else:
    print("This book isn't available in Library.")
file.close()
```

After else: it prints "This book isn't available in Library" continuously

Comment: Watch out for indentation issues. If your `if/else` statements are within `for` loop, they should be indented properly.

Comment: Apart from just the code, you should also provide a small version of `database.txt` and the input that you enter manually.

Comment: Thank you I am not too sure what you mean by that Eugene Pakhomov (sorry beginner here x)

Answer (score 2):

I think with the indentation corrected your original code would be:

```
file = open('database.txt','r')
x = input("Please enter the title of the book you are looking for?")
print("%s %10s %8s %22s %11s"%\
  ("ID","Title","Author","Purchase Date","Member ID"))
for line in file:
    if x in line.split():
        print(line)
    else:
        print("This book isn't available in Library.")
file.close()
```

And the reason why you are continually printing "This book isn't available in Library." is because your loop is asking for every line in the file to either
1) print the line 
or
2) print the "This book isn't available in Library."

So if your file is say 1000 lines, no matter what, you will print *something* 1000 times.

Instead, maybe start off with assigning a boolean variable that keeps track as to whether a book is found or not. Then loop through the lines in the database.txt file looking for the book of interest.

If the book is found, you can change that variable, and print the line containing the book, continually doing this **inside** the loop.

If the book is not found, then **outside** of the loop is where you would print the "This book isn't available in Library." message.

```
file = open('database.txt','r')

x = input("Please enter the title of the book you are looking for?")

print("%s %10s %8s %22s %11s"%\
  ("ID","Title","Author","Purchase Date","Member ID"))

book_not_found = True

for line in file:
    if x in line.split():
        book_not_found = False
        print(line, end = '')

if book_not_found:
    print("This book isn't available in Library.")

file.close()
```

And also yes, as commented above by Eugene Pakhomov, it's easier to trouble shoot if you provide an example of the input and the expected output.

Comment: Thank you! However, now when I print, it only prints one of the copies of my book from the database.txt file. For example, there are 5 copies of Book_1 but after using your suggestion it no longer prints out all the Book_1's... sorry I am beginner at python therefore struggling.

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer. But again, it is far easier to get answers to questions if you explicitly note what the input is, and the expected output.